# Foreign key in two tables

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have two existing tables with "circular" foreign keys, that is, table `A` references PK in table `B` and vice versa.

Now, I would like to insert rows to both tables. Rows have columns that reference currently added values from the other table, so error occures.

How to fill-up the two tables referencing each other? Using `Oracle PL/SQL`.

Comment: What if you add another *`join`* table between these two tables?

Comment: Agree with user below - bad bad data design.  Split the data out correctly so only one depends on the other.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a valid reason for the circular reference, you can also get around this by recreating your FK and specifying the DEFERRABLE clause.  You can then either also specify the INITIALLY DEFERRED clause when creating the constraint or issue the following statement before your inserts:

```
SET CONSTRAINT <constraint_name> DEFERRED;
```

If a constraint is in the deferred state, constraint checking will wait until the end of the transaction (when an implicit or explicit commit is submitted).

Answer (score 6):

Remove the circular references.

Redesign the two tables and their relationship - without circular references.

Comment: Yes, check this article (Date: July 1999): [sql-by-design-the-circular-reference](http://www.sqlmag.com/article/quering/sql-by-design-the-circular-reference)

Comment: +1 Circular references are a doubly bad thing.  They are an inaccurate interpretation of real life, and they are a real PITN to work with.

Comment: It's always a good thing to tell people that the thing your DBMS doesn't support is bad in the first place. It's much easier than just supporting it and letting your customers hang themselves if they want to.